# What is "Direction Cosine" in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

My professor wrote the following thing on the board:

$$\text{Direction Cosine: } \cos(x, y) = \dfrac {(x, y)}{||x|| \cdot ||y||}$$

$(x, y)$ represents an inner product. This was in the context of inner product spaces over $\mathbb{C}$.  It wasn't very clear from the context if this was just a definition, or an actual theorem.

I am inclined to say it is a definition, because as a theorem it doesn't really make sense. For example, I took $V$ as $C^{1 \times 1}$ and $x = 2+i, y = 3-2i$. With the usual inner product, $(x, y) = 4-7i$. But then $\cos(4-7i)$ did not seem to be equal to the RHS.

Based on this, I'm pretty sure it's just supposed to be a definition. But I would like to make sure.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I get $(2+i,3-2i)=4+7i$, remember that $(x,y):=x\cdot\bar y$. However it seems true that the statement doesn't make sense for complex vector spaces

Comment: @Masacroso Ummmmm really? Unless I copied it wrong, my professor wrote $(x,y):=\bar x \cdot y$

Comment: it is possible that he is using a different convention.

Comment: check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Dot_product_and_generalisations). In complex vector spaces the real part of the dot product is taken instead of just the dot product

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a definition. It's basically the most sensible way to define anything resembling angles in general inner product spaces (especially over $\Bbb R$, but still).

Comment: Thanks. But even so, we're not really defining the "angle", right? Just the "cosine" of the "angle"? Or is the "angle" also defined as the complex number $z$ with the smallest modulus such that $\cos (z) =\dfrac {(x, y)}{||x|| \cdot ||y||}$?

Comment: @Ovi I have mostly seen angles defined this way with real inner products, and in that case, yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

It is a definition of a function of two variables (that is, $\cos(x,y)$ is not "the cosine of the scalar product").

The idea is that in the usual euclidean plane, if there is an angle of $\theta$ between $x$ and $y$ then $\cos \theta = \frac{(x,y)}{||x||\cdot ||y||}$, so this formula generalizes this, by defining $\cos (x,y)$ for a pair of vectors instead of the angle that they determine.

Comment: but this doesn't holds for complex vector spaces, at least as stated in the body of the question

Comment: @Masacroso : yes of course, that's why we generalize to complex vector spaces with this formula !

Comment: I dont think so, the generalization that I know is that $\cos\theta=\frac{\Re(x\cdot\bar y)}{\|x\|\cdot\|y\|}$

Comment: @Masacroso : that's not a generalization, that's just calling the euclidean plane $\mathbb C$ and using complex operations to define the scalar product.